# Tomcat 8.0 and GeoServer 2.17 on Windows Server, trouble upgrading JDK to latest version

Tags: geoserver, java, windows, tomcat, environment-variable

I have Windows server running Apache Tomcat 8 and GeoServer 2.17.  The JDK installed when setup is older, JDK 1.8.0_73.

I've now installed JDK 1.8.0_251.  I changed my global env variable JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\jre from JAVA_HOME=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre

I cannot find anywhere a conf or XML or other file under the Tomcat folder that would specifically point to a particular Java version.  I assumed then that environment variable Java_Home would be followed.

I've restarted Tomcat, then rebooted the machine entirely.  When Tomcat starts, I go to GeoServer's Status page, and it clearly states that the JVM in use is still the _073 version.

Any hints as to where I would find that Tomcat is configured to use a particular JVM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running Tomcat as Windows service, then tomcat8w can help to configure new JRE. Go to Tomcat/bin, find tomcat8w.exe, execute in commandline:

```
Tomcat8w.exe //ES//Tomcat8    (Change Tomcat8 to your service name)
```

you'll see the Tomcat 8 properties dialog

[image: Tomcat service configuration]

Set the JAVA Virtual Machine to your new installed one.

Please refer to question
[How to change Java version used by TOMCAT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4072260/how-to-change-java-version-used-by-tomcat)
for more detailed discussion.

Comment: Excellent! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you.